# Can't get the selected text of Bootstrap Dropdown Menu with React+Jquery

Tags: jquery, reactjs, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4

Here is a Bootstrap 4 code of a dropdown menu:

```
<div className="btn-group show">
  <button className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" data-type="fontFamily" style="width: 100px;">Avenir Next</button>
  <div className="dropdown-menu">
       <a className="dropdown-item" href="#" style="font-family: &quot;Avenir Next&quot;;">Avenir Next</a><a className="dropdown-item" href="#" style="font-family: Baghdad;">Baghdad</a>
       <a className="dropdown-item" href="#" style="font-family: Helvetica;">Helvetica</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" style="font-family: Monotype;">Monotype</a>
       <a className="dropdown-item" href="#" style="font-family: &quot;Times New Roman&quot;;">Times New Roman</a>
       <a className="dropdown-item" href="#" style="font-family: &quot;Lucida Grande&quot;;">Lucida Grande</a>
  <div className="dropdown-divider"></div>
       <a className="dropdown-item" href="#" style="font-family: &quot;Lucida Grande&quot;;">Lucida Grande</a>
 </div>
```

Here is the react part :

```
componentDidMount(){

  $('.dropdown-item').click((e) => {
      console.log('text', $(e.currentTarget).text());
   });

}
```

When clicking on a dropdown, nothing happen. I don't know why.

Please help

Answer (score -1):

`class="..."` should be `className="..."` assuming you're using JSX.

also begs the question why you're using jquery + React...

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, I just edited my post. It was "className" instead of "class". I also use jQuery because of fabricJS. This block actually comme from fabriceJs code which only work with jQuery in my case